# Definition of ワガハイ

Tags: word-choice, words

While I was playing Persona 5 JAP version on the PS4, I noticed that Morgana, one of the characters in the game refer to itself using " ワガハイ ".

Why does it use that? and what does it really mean?

I refer to Morgana to " it " because it's a talking cat

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since it's a cat, I feel like it may be in reference to this book titled [吾輩は猫である](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Am_a_Cat).

ワガハイ or 吾輩 in kanji, is an archaic first person address term.

> Why does it use that? and what does it really mean?

It carries a feeling of pompousness and self-importance (which is of course very important for a cat). Wikipedia says:

> Sōseki's original title, Wagahai wa Neko de Aru, uses very high-register phrasing more appropriate to a nobleman, conveying a grandiloquence and self-importance intended to sound ironic, since the speaker, an anthropomorphised domestic cat, is a house cat, not feral.

Comment: ありがとう for your detailed answer

Answer (score 1):

ワガハイ is just one of archaisms for "me" (also see 「拙者」、「わらわ」、「わし」, e.t.c).